# Web based software to queue/reserve machines for use

Tags: php, django, queue, mediawiki, scheduler

I'm in need of some sort of software based way to reserve the use of a couple machines. There about 5 different machines used in a lab that are shared among everybody but people need to schedule the days/times they want to use these machines. This is currently handled with pen/paper and you need to physically walk place to place to see when they're free and available for sign-up. I've been tasked with moving this system to a private webserver that currently runs an installation of mediawiki.

I've looked for extensions for mediawiki itself, but I couldn't find any kind of scheduler/planner/queue system that is premade that allows users to reserve a time frame/day to use machine. Additionally it would be nice if anyone could sign up but users were restricted from removing others from the queue(which is why a traditional calendar software with the honor system wouldn't exactly work). The solution doesn't need to be embedded within medawiki itself but must be able to be hosted off of a webserver, do you guys have any suggestions on how I can approach this? The best I can come up with is to buckle down and write my own php/django based site to handle this(I'm not very experienced with either). While I do have time I want to make sure there isn't something available I missed before dedicating my time to writing a custom application, and would appreciate anyone who could help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Software requests are off-topic here so this will probably get closed soon, but maybe this helps: http://www.php.brickhost.com/ I have not used it myself, but it may do what you need.

Comment: That seems interesting, looks like something we may be able to use. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I've not used this:

[phpscheduleit](http://www.php.brickhost.com/)